# EntityFarmeworkCore Scafold error on reverse enginearing

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm currently using this Scaffold-DbContext

```
"Server=XXXXXX;database=XXX;user id=XX;password=XXXX;Trusted_Connection=True;Integrated Security = false;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Entity command to Reverse enginearing of an existing database this the error i'm getting...........................

System.ArgumentException: The string argument 'originalIdentifier' cannot be empty.
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CandidateNamingService.GenerateCandidateIdentifier(String originalIdentifier)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CandidateNamingService.GenerateCandidateIdentifier(DatabaseColumn originalColumn)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.<GetPropertyName>b__18_1(DatabaseColumn c)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpNamer`1.GetName(T item)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpUniqueNamer`1.GetName(T item)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.GetPropertyName(DatabaseColumn column)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.VisitColumn(EntityTypeBuilder builder, DatabaseColumn column)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.VisitColumns(EntityTypeBuilder builder, ICollection`1 columns)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.VisitTable(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DatabaseTable table)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.VisitTables(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, ICollection`1 tables)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.VisitDatabaseModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DatabaseModel databaseModel)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.Create(DatabaseModel databaseModel, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineerScaffolder.ScaffoldModel(String connectionString, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions databaseOptions, ModelReverseEngineerOptions modelOptions, ModelCodeGenerationOptions codeOptions)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContext(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputDbContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
The string argument 'originalIdentifier' cannot be empty.
```

Comment: have you added all proper references to project, like "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" or others?  it looks an inner function is expecting a parameter, but it didn't get it since a reference is missed.

Comment: Yes i have done that, This seems fine with other database but the error percuiliar to a particular kind of microsoft sql db